# How to launch tmux with pre-opened second window and execute commands?

Tags: bash, debian, tmux

There's possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213849/how-to-launch-tmux-and-automatically-run-commands) but it's closed and unanswered.

As I'm using chef for automation, would be nice to automate tmux launch with pre-launched python web server and second window opened. (this is specifically for my development environment). And only way of doing this probably specifying parameters from command line.

Commands which I want to execute are in window with title "daemon":

```
source bin/activate
cd project
DEBUG=1 python app.py
```

I'm unable to find which command line parameters allows to pre-execute commands when launching tmux, and also to open more windows on launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a session without attaching to it (using the `-d` option), so that you can send additional `tmux` commands to open the second window before actually attaching.

```
tmux new-session -t mysession -d 'source bin/activate; cd project; DEBUG=1 python app.py'
tmux new-window -t mysession
tmux attach-session -t mysession
```